# CLIPS decision maker frame work

Tags: clips, expert-system

I am just getting started with CLIPS and I have found a couple tutorials but I can't find many example projects. I am just trying to create a simple system to help someone pick a laptop. nothing crazy just 15 or so questions with 10 possible outcomes.

Can anyone point me towards an example project that does something similar? (maybe diagnosing some problem or recommending something else) I typically learn best from hacking together my own starter projects from examples on the internet but can't find anything similar to what I want to create

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could modify the wine recommendation example to do something similar with laptops: https://sourceforge.net/p/clipsrules/code/HEAD/tree/branches/63x/examples/wine.clp

There are also GUI wrappers for the wine examples (and others) for .NET, Java, iOS, and CGI available here: http://www.clipsrules.net/?q=node/3